# Adding numbers in a dynamic string separated by some token in the kusto table

Tags: parsing, kql

Suppose there is a table like below:

```
datatable(str:string) [
    "a,b,2,10,d,e;a,b,c,14,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
    "a,b,c,11,d,e;a,b,c,12,d,e;a,b,c,13,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
    "a,b,c,20,d,e;a,b,c,25,d,e",
]
```

I need to add 4th value in each string separated by semicolon
e.g. Answer for above table is

```
10+14+10=34
11+12+13+10=46
20+25=45
```

I tried below which works for single row:

```
let calculateCostForARow = (str:string) {
    print row = split(str,";")
    | mv-expand row
    | parse row with * "," * "," * "," cost:long "," * 
    | summarize sum(cost)
};
calculateCostForARow("a,b,c,11,d,e;a,b,c,12,d,e;a,b,c,13,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e")
```

but doesn't work for table as to_scalar has issues with table

```
let calculateCostForARow = (str:string) {
    toscalar(print row = split(str,";")
    | mv-expand row
    | parse row with * "," * "," * "," cost:long "," * 
    | summarize sum(cost))
};
datatable(str:string) [
    "a,b,c,10,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
    "a,b,c,10,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
    "a,b,c,10,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
]
| project calculateCostForARow(str)
```

Let me know if there are other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this, using `mv-apply`:

```
datatable(str:string) [
    "a,b,2,10,d,e;a,b,c,14,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
    "a,b,c,11,d,e;a,b,c,12,d,e;a,b,c,13,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e",
    "a,b,c,20,d,e;a,b,c,25,d,e",
]
| mv-apply s = split(str, ";") on (
    summarize result = sum(tolong(split(s, ",", 3)[0]))
)
```

| str | result |
| --- | --- |
| a,b,2,10,d,e;a,b,c,14,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e | 34 |
| a,b,c,11,d,e;a,b,c,12,d,e;a,b,c,13,d,e;a,b,c,10,d,e | 46 |
| a,b,c,20,d,e;a,b,c,25,d,e | 45 |